# Genymotion in Ubuntu running on VM from windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, genymotion

Iam tried to setup genymotion inside Ubuntu ,were ubuntu is running on VM from windows. But it is always getting ip is not setup error, but everything is correct. Anybody help me out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genymotion does not work inside a VM, because the virtual Android device won't be able to access the GPU if Genymotion itself has been virtualized.